# How to use dataset values in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, dataset

I am taking values(currency rates) from [web service](http://cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?op=GetCursOnDate) in the form of dataset

```
using Overstock.OverstockCurrency;
using System.Data;
```

This is my action

```
public ActionResult CurrencyConvertor()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DailyInfoSoapClient().GetCursOnDate(DateTime.Today);
        return View(ds);
    }
```

I have no idea how to use dataset values in my view. So my question is how to use dataset values in view? In what form I should send from controller to view? How to use sent data in view?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to convert to DataTable and send Datatable to the view

```
public ActionResult CurrencyConvertor()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DailyInfoSoapClient().GetCursOnDate(DateTime.Today);
            DataTable Table = ds.Tables[0];
            return View(Table);
        }
```

In the view, I am taking columns and rows:

```
    @model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CurrencyConvertor";
}

<h2>CurrencyConvertor</h2>

<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Column)     
    {          
        <th>@col.ColumnName</th> 
    }     
    </tr> 
    </thead>         
    <tbody> 
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)     
    {         
        <tr> 
        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)         
        {              
            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
        }         
        </tr> 
    }     
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

I have run the application. It is giving this compiler error:

> CS1061: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Column' and no extension method 'Column' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source error:

> Line 13:     @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Column)

To what I should give reference(@using) in order to use Model.Column?

Comment: What is the result of `GetCursOnDate` ?

Comment: it returns dataset of currency rates according to given date.I have taken it from here: http://cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?op=GetCursOnDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to have a model which you can pass to the view.

I don't know what your `GetCursOnDate()` method returns (I mean what is the form of that data set) but in any case I'm pretty sure you have a known structure of that set.

Knowing this, you have to create a model which maps your `DataSet` data that you are interested in and then you pass the model to the view as an argument.

If you don't know the result of `GetCursOnDate()` you can use the debugger to search for the values you are interested in.

```
public ActionResult CurrencyConvertor()
{
    DataSet ds = new DailyInfoSoapClient().GetCursOnDate(DateTime.Today);
    Dictionary<string, decimal> model = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    model.Add("eur", dataset_value_for_eur);
    return View(model);
}
```

In view:

```
@model Dictionary<string,decimal> // put this in the first line of your view
```

Or you can have another kind of model like:

```
public class CurrencyViewModel {
    public decimal EUR {get;set;}
    public decimal USD {get;set;}
}
```

And then just fill the values from your dataset and pass the model to the view.

In view:

```
@model the_namespace.CurrencyViewModel // put this in the first line of your view
```

Comment: Tnx, I will try to identify the what GetCursOnDate() returns.